# Unexpected indices sort problem on a compute kernel

Tags: parallel-processing, glsl, gpgpu, vulkan, spir-v

I have a weird problem when I try to do an indices sort in descending order. I'm pretty sure I'm missing some basic idea about how GPUs work, as I would expect this program to execute fine:

```
layout(binding = 0, std430) buffer _6_3
{
    uint _m0[];
} _3;

layout(binding = 1, std430) buffer _8_4
{
    uint _m0[];
} _4;

uint _51(uint _63, uint _64)
{
    uint _66 = 0u;
    uint _67 = 1u;
    for (;;)
    {
        uint _72 = _66;
        if (_72 < 150u)
        {
            memoryBarrierBuffer();
            barrier();
            uint _76 = atomicCounter(_3._m0[_72]);
            memoryBarrierBuffer();
            barrier();
            _67 += uint(((_76 == _63) && (_72 > _64)) || (_76 < _63));
            _66++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    uint _87 = _67;
    uint _90 = _64 + 1u;
    memoryBarrierBuffer();
    barrier();
    _3._m0[150u - _87] = _90;
    memoryBarrierBuffer();
    barrier();
    return _90;
}

void main()
{
    uint _49 = _3._m0[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x];
    uint _50 = _51(_49, gl_GlobalInvocationID.x);
}
```

This program works for small inputs -- let us suppose an ordered list of natural numbers from 1 to 500. If we replace the 150u with 50 or 75, the result is as expected: the first 75 numbers descend from 75 to 1, after which they start from 76 towards 500.

The problem is that with inputs over 100 some of the indices get shuffled. The results are complete gibberish of structure, but the indices, of course, stay within the bounds. **The weird thing is that if the while invariant is incremented to say, 5000 for a loop of 500 elements, the sort starts working again.**

Any idea what the problem might be? I'm quite certain I'm failing to understand some basic synchronization. To my understanding, I should not need any other barriers in my code except before the indices swap at the end of the function.

For what it is worth, this is a translation of the following SPIR-V function:

```
%rankDown = OpFunction %1 None %rankdown_uint_signature
%self = OpFunctionParameter %1
%sindex = OpFunctionParameter %1
%rd = OpLabel
%iter = OpVariable %u32ptr Function %uint_0
%rank = OpVariable %u32ptr Function %uint_1

    OpBranch %while_start
    %while_start = OpLabel
    OpLoopMerge %endloop %continueloop None
    OpBranch %rankloop
    %rankloop = OpLabel
    %rloopload = OpLoad %1 %iter
    %loopgate = OpULessThan %bool %rloopload %uint_500
    OpBranchConditional %loopgate %start %endloop
    %start = OpLabel

        %_thrdValue = OpAccessChain %_ptr_Uniform_uint %_ %uint_0 %rloopload
        OpControlBarrier %uint_1 %uint_1 %UniformMemory
        %thrdValue = OpAtomicLoad %1 %_thrdValue %uint_1 %UniformMemory
        OpControlBarrier %uint_1 %uint_1 %UniformMemory

        %smaller = OpULessThan %bool %thrdValue %self

        %same = OpIEqual %bool %thrdValue %self
        %_is_after = OpUGreaterThan %bool %rloopload %sindex
        %_if_gate = OpLogicalAnd %bool %same %_is_after

        %if_gate2 = OpLogicalOr %bool %_if_gate %smaller
        %sel = OpSelect %1 %if_gate2 %uint_1 %uint_0

        %rankLoad = OpLoad %1 %rank
        %rank_adder = OpIAdd %1 %rankLoad %sel
        OpStore %rank %rank_adder

    OpBranch %continueloop
    %continueloop = OpLabel

        %iterLoad = OpLoad %1 %iter
        %iterAdd = OpIAdd %1 %iterLoad %uint_1
        OpStore %iter %iterAdd

    OpBranch %while_start
    %endloop = OpLabel

    %rankll = OpLoad %1 %rank
    %ow_index = OpISub %1 %uint_500 %rankll
    %_overwrite = OpAccessChain %_ptr_Uniform_uint %_ %uint_0 %ow_index
    %ow_index2 = OpIAdd %1 %sindex %uint_1

    OpControlBarrier %uint_1 %uint_1 %UniformMemory
    OpStore %_overwrite %ow_index2
    OpControlBarrier %uint_1 %uint_1 %UniformMemory

    OpReturnValue %ow_index2
OpFunctionEnd
```

As an example, if we change 150u to 250u and visualize the results, we get the following:

[image: example with 250u]

Here we can see that the ordering shows that for some cases, the while loop doesn't seem to run enough times -- there exist duplicate values within the results, and some values disappear.

Any input is appreciated!